# What happens to memory during Polymorphism?

Tags: oop, memory, language-agnostic

I've always wondered, when you cast an object pointer to its base class, what exactly happens to the memory? I presume that the memory storing all the member functions and variables in the sub class are still there, just 'off-limits' now. Is this right? If so, how do abstract/virtual functions work? How come the sub class implementation can be called from a base class pointer in this case?

Also, does it vary depending on the language? Obviously C++ uses the stack and the heap, whereas Java would only use the heap.. Does this mean the memory for the polymorphic relationship is handled differently?

And how do things like private, protected and even virtual inheritance work in relation to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are asking is implementation detail.
Broadly speaking the usual approach is to store a pointer to a table of function pointers as part of the object (the functions are not part of the actual object's memory footprint) and depending on the concrete object this table ([vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) in C++, some similar construct in `Java` I imagine) points to the actual runtime object's methods and as a result the fact that you are using a pointer to the base class does not affect you from actually calling a method overriden by the derived class

> And how do things like private, protected and even virtual inheritance
>   work in relation to this

This is not related to your question. Modifiers (public/private/protected) are a *static* time construct. I.e. the *compiler* enforces usage according to the modifiers. The underlying memory is unrelated here.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, nothing at all happens to the memory.  The casting just affects how the pointer is used by anyone else in the program who uses it.

Check this link out for more information on how this is implemented:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table